# Add bearer token authorization input to SwaggerUI generated from OpenAPI doc

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I want to add a nice input text or something similar to SwaggerUI. I generate the swaggerUI from openAPI docs and don't build the swaggerUI myself using an index page etc. Something similar to

[image: this button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following declarations to your OpenAPI doc:

```
security:
  - bearerAuth: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```